# How to get group by sum using SQL query

Tags: sql

How can I get the quantity in "BXQty" column as per column "F" shown in screenshot?
We do not have column E. Column E is just for reference.
[image: Excel Result]

I am using the below query.

```
SELECT              *,
       r2.cumulative/r2."U_NumInSale" "BXQty"
FROM   (SELECT   *,
             Sum("OtherQty") OVER (partition BY r1."UOM" ORDER BY r1."UOM", r1."OtherQty" DESC rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumulativefrom
             (
                    SELECT *,
                           mod(cast(r."Quantity" AS int),r."U_NumInSale") "OtherQty"
                    FROM   (
                                  SELECT itms."DocEntry",
                                         itms."ItemCode",
                                         itms."Dscription"AS "Discriptn1" ,
                                         itms."Quantity",
                                         itms."InvQty",
                                         t0."NumInSale" "U_NumInSale",
                                         cast(itms."Quantity" AS decimal(19,0))"PackQty",
                                         t0."SalUnitMsr"
                                                ||''
                                                ||cast(t0."NumInSale" AS int) uom,
                                         t0."SalUnitMsr"                      uomstr
                                  FROM   "PM_PROD".dln1                       AS itms
                                  JOIN   "PM_PROD".oitm t0
                                  ON     itms."ItemCode"=t0."ItemCode"
                                  WHERE  itms."DocEntry"=3216
                                  AND    mod(itms."Quantity",t0."NumInSale")>0r)r1)r2
    ORDER BY r2."UOM",
             r2."OtherQty" DESC
```

Comment: It would great if you format your SQL query.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: We are using SAP HANA DB.

Answer (score 0):

Using data in excel screenshot, I came up with solution at following link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c61dc1/5

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
    ([Item] varchar(6), [GroupQty] int, [UOM] varchar(5), [Qty] int, [Group] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO myTable
    ([Item], [GroupQty], [UOM], [Qty], [Group])
VALUES
    ('Item1', 30, 'Bag30', 15, 1),
    ('Item2', 30, 'Bag31', 15, 1),
    ('Item3', 30, 'Bag32', 10, 2),
    ('Item4', 30, 'Bag33', 20, 2),
    ('Item5', 30, 'Bag34', 15, 3),
    ('Item6', 30, 'Bag35', 15, 3),
    ('Item7', 30, 'Bag36', 5, 4),
    ('Item8', 30, 'Bag37', 5, 4),
    ('Item9', 30, 'Bag38', 5, 4),
    ('Item10', 30, 'Bag39', 5, 4)
;
select *, 
case
  when min(item)over (partition by [group])=item 
  then sum(qty) over(partition by [group]) 
 end as BagQty
from myTable
```

Comment: We do not have Group column. Group column is just for reference. Also Column UOM='Bag'+'GroupQty'. We are trying to get the calculations based on GroupQty and Qty columns.

Comment: 1. Yes, the UOM was a excel typo from me.
2. if you do not have group column, are you trying something like running total and limit

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, we are trying to get running sum. If running sum is>=GroupQty then it should reset the running total from next row.